# problem with the canvas rendering. showing completely

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter-canvas

I have a problem with rendering the canvas. which if running the code You can see that some parts are missing from line 1560 onwards.

this is my sample code
please help me answer the problem
thank you.

```
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, Frame, IntVar
import customtkinter


class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("DEMO")
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")
        width = 800
        height = 500
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green
        customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height,
                                    (screenwidth - width)/1.1, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


        self.btn_checkbox = []
        self.interests=[]

        for i in range(2000):
            self.interests.append([f'num{i})',i])
        self.chks = [BooleanVar() for i in self.interests]

        self.my_labelframe_list = customtkinter.CTkFrame(
            root, corner_radius=10)
        self.my_labelframe_list.place(x=350, y=50, width=420, height=420)  
        
        self.my_canvas =customtkinter.CTkCanvas(self.my_labelframe_list)

        self.my_scrollbar = customtkinter.CTkScrollbar(self.my_labelframe_list, command=self.my_canvas.yview)

        self.my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.my_scrollbar.set)
        self.my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.my_canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.second_frame = Frame(self.my_canvas)
        self.my_canvas.create_window(
            (0, 0), window=self.second_frame, anchor="nw")
        
        self.my_labelframe_list.place(x=350, y=50, width=420, height=420)
        self.my_canvas.place(x=150, y=30, width=250, height=380)
        self.my_scrollbar.place(x=400, y=30, height=380)
        
        self.list_friend()
    def list_friend(self):
        if self.btn_checkbox != []:
            for checkbuttonm in self.btn_checkbox:
                checkbuttonm.destroy()
            self.btn_checkbox = []

        if self.interests != []:
            
            for i, s in enumerate(self.interests):
                checkbuttonm = ttk.Checkbutton(
                    self.second_frame, text=f'{i+1}. {s[0]}', variable=self.chks[i],)
                checkbuttonm.pack(anchor=W)  
                self.btn_checkbox.append(checkbuttonm)

        

if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = customtkinter.CTk()  
        app = App(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

I have a problem with the canvas rendering. which, if you look at the attached picture It can be seen that some sections are missing.

This is my sample code.
please help me answer the problem
Thank you..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The canvas isn't infinitely wide and tall. You're probably bumping into a limit.